# use python 2.7.13 in Redhat 6.7 instead of the default python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix, redhat, python-2.6

I want to use python 2.7 by deafult in Redhat 6.7 distro to run my scripts currently the distro is having python 2.6 by default which I dont want to use.
So far what I have done :

changed the etc/bashrc file and added the path

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

after this when I type python it shows me the same old 2.6 version and scripts fail to run which has to be run using 2.7 version.
When i call my python it should show me 2.7 and scripts should automatically take that version to run.

For ex:-
I want to run a simple script which will print the data from an api url

```
import urllib
import json
url = 'www.jamesst/api.com'
data = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
print data
```

This cannot be run in ver 2.6 it requires 2.7 
if any alternative is there for code itself, kindly share the same.

Any help would be great.

Comment: try typing `bash` to get yourself a new shell and then type `type -a python` and make sure you see both Python interpreters.

Comment: I have already installed python2.7 in my usr/local/bin- I have done a altinstall so that the default python remains untouched.

Comment: @gregory I am unable to see both the interpreters type -a python gives as usr/bin/python while it should also show usr/local/bin/python2.7

Comment: OH. If you want `python2.7` to be available under the name `python`, just make a symlink. `cd /usr/local/bin ; ln -s python2.7 python`

Comment: thanks Gregory , It worked now ,
$which is python > gives me /usr/local/bin/python2.7
but the script above which was running well in python2.7 tested on a windows OS is now not running in redHat 6.7 OS python2.7 is there anything else I need to install along with python2.7 in Redhat OS?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Red Hat Software Collections (SCL) version of Python 2.7.  SCL install alongside the original 2.6 version so it won't mess with the OS. There's a simple "SCL enable" command and then they usual yum install.  Then follow the docs so that 2.7 is default for your apps.

See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html/2.2_Release_Notes/chap-RHSCL.html#sect-RHSCL-Features

Comment: before you use python27(installed by scl), you have to enable the module using "scl enable python27 bash"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `alternatives` utility in order to use python27 as your default python using the following steps:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
```

This command will add python to alternatives and make python27 your default python's version.